# Flutter 3.0.0: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart': Failed assertion: line 147 pos 12: '_overlay != null': is not true

Tags: dart, flutter-layout

I have this overlay error on my login page and i'm unable to determine how to fix it despite several similar issues on stackoverflow. How do i trace where the overlay error comes from and how to fix it. I'm also unsure which widget is causing this overlay bug so i'd love help with the same.

Find my login screen code below

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:how/controllers/auth/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:how/helpers/app_styles.dart';
import 'package:how/helpers/custom_loader.dart';
import 'package:how/helpers/size_config.dart';
import 'package:how/routes/route_helper.dart';
import 'package:how/widgets/description_text.dart';
import 'package:how/widgets/show_custom_snackbar.dart';
import 'package:how/widgets/show_success_snackbar.dart';
import 'package:how/widgets/title_text.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  String authPassword = '';
  bool isPasswordVisible = true;

  void _isLogin(AuthController authController) {
    String email = emailController.text.trim();
    String password = passwordController.text.trim();

    if (email.isEmpty) {
      showCustomSnackBar("Enter your Email Address", title: "Email Address");
    } else if (!GetUtils.isEmail(email)) {
      showCustomSnackBar("Enter a valid Email Address", title: "Email Address");
    } else if (password.isEmpty) {
      showCustomSnackBar("Enter your Password", title: "Password");
    } else {
      authController.login(email, password).then((status) {
        if (status.isSuccess) {
          showSuccessSnackBar("Login Successful");
          Get.toNamed(RouteHelper.getInitialPage());
        } else {
          showCustomSnackBar(status.message);
        }
      });
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<AuthController>(builder: (authController) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: AppStyles.appPrimaryColor,
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.height80),
              // #login, #welcome
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.width20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/img/logo-white.png',
                      width: SizeConfig.width150,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.height20),

              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(SizeConfig.radius50),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(SizeConfig.radius50)),
                  ),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.width30),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: SizeConfig.height30,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            AppStyles.authLogin,
                            style: UITextStyles.authTitleStyle,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: SizeConfig.height30,
                          ),
                          // #email,
                          // #password
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.width10),
                                child: buildEmail(),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.width10),
                                child: buildPassword(),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.width10),
                                margin:
                                    EdgeInsets.only(left: SizeConfig.width150),
                                child: RichText(
                                  text: TextSpan(
                                    text: 'Forgot Password?',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                                        fontSize: SizeConfig.font15),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.height30),
                          // #login
                          // ButtonWidget(
                          //   text: AppStyles.login,
                          //   onClicked: (){},
                          // ),
                          !authController.isLoading
                              ? GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    _isLogin(authController);
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: SizeConfig.width200,
                                    height: SizeConfig.height50,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                            SizeConfig.radius10),
                                        color: AppStyles.appPrimaryColor),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: TitleTextWidget(
                                          titleText: 'Login',
                                          titleColor:
                                              AppStyles.appSecondaryColor),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : CustomLoader(),

                          SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.height50),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              DescriptionTextWidget(
                                  descriptionText: 'Don\'t have an account? '),
                              RichText(
                                text: TextSpan(
                                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                    ..onTap = () => Get.toNamed(
                                        RouteHelper.getRegisterPage()),
                                  text: 'Register Here',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'klasik',
                                      color: AppStyles.appSecondaryColor),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget buildEmail() => TextField(
        controller: emailController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'abc@example.com',
          labelText: AppStyles.email,
          prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.mail_outline_sharp),
          suffixIcon: emailController.text.isEmpty
              ? Container(width: 0)
              : IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                  onPressed: () => emailController.clear(),
                ),
          focusColor: AppStyles.appSecondaryColor,
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppStyles.appPrimaryColor)),
          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppStyles.appSecondaryColor)),
        ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        autofocus: true,
      );

  Widget buildPassword() => TextField(
        controller: passwordController,
        onChanged: (value) => setState(() => authPassword = value),
        onSubmitted: (value) => setState(() => authPassword = value),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: AppStyles.password,
          labelText: AppStyles.password,
          prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock_outline_sharp),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: isPasswordVisible
                ? const Icon(Icons.visibility_off)
                : const Icon(Icons.visibility),
            onPressed: () =>
                setState(() => isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible),
          ),
          focusColor: AppStyles.appSecondaryColor,
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppStyles.appPrimaryColor)),
          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppStyles.appSecondaryColor)),
        ),
        obscureText: isPasswordVisible,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      );
}
```

Comment: have you find any solution..?